# will continuous keyboard work in password field of a android app?

Tags: android, mobile

I am testing Android app,  i am unable to type my password in the password field by using the continuous Keyboard in the device?

is this correct scenario?

Can someone help me in this issue?

Comment: continuous Keyboard? Which keyboard are you talking about? What is your Android OS version?

Answer (score 0):

check out the inputType attribute for editText https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

I think setting inputtype = "textpassword" will work for you.

Comment: Hi, i asking in testers perspective. Just i want give my input in the password field by using continual Keyboard